# How to get the actual x/y position of an element in SVG with transformations and matrices

Tags: javascript, matrix, svg, transform

I need to get the x/y positions of an element that is written like this in SVG:

```
<g transform="scale(10,10)" id="g6558">
    <text transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,236.532,417.253)" id="text6560">
        <tspan x="0 4.448" y="0" id="tspan6562">10</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

How do I get the current position of the `tspan` element in this case? I have to manually calculate them as I can't use `getBBox()` or other native functions because I'm using a Flash-wrapper to display the SVG (http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) which only supports basic attributes, tag names etc.

How are the matrices and transformations caluclated on the x/y position of the element?

Comment: Just a question. Have you evaluated RaphaelJS ? Support for SVG is great, and you get `getBBox()` for free :-)

Comment: The graphics are already created, I just want to display them - not create or edit them in any way. Using SVGWeb was quite neat at the time because it enabled me to support most browsers and still have the exact same display of the graphics thanks to flash...

Comment: What values can you access? You say basic attributes, does that include the `transform` attribute?

Comment: Yes - any attribute. But when I access that, I just get the string `matrix(...)` returned - but I don't know how to calculate the actual x/y positions from that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As well as i understood your problem, you need to know the x and y co-ordinates of an element, after it is transformed.

Mathematically, all transformations can be represented as 3x3 transformation matrices of the following form:

```
a   b   e
c   d   f
0   0   1
```

Since only six values are used in the above 3x3 matrix, a transformation matrix is also expressed as a vector: `[a b c d e f]`. 
a and d responsible for scaling in x and y respectively, whereas e and f gives you the translated axis in the x and y respectively.
So In your code which is

```
     <text transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,236.532,417.253)" id="text6560">
      <tspan x="0 4.448" y="0" id="tspan6562">10</tspan>
    </text>
```

Element text is translated 236.532 in the x-axis 417.253 in the y-axis.
So tspan x point becomes 236.. + 4.4.. and y point  417.. + 0.

Comment: That's a really good explanation. I will go forth and try to use it in my program. You're a life-saver! :)