# How we get x and y from the transform matrix?

Tags: c#, math, matrix, svg, transform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the actual x/y position of an element in SVG with transformations and matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851023/how-to-get-the-actual-x-y-position-of-an-element-in-svg-with-transformations-and)

I need to get the x/y positions of an element that is written like this in SVG:

```
<image
   y="-421.28461"
   x="335.27295"
   id="image2991"
   xlink:href="file:///C:/Users/tom/Documents/t.jpg"
   height="369"
   width="360"
   transform="matrix(0.22297057,0.97482518,-0.97482518,0.22297057,0,0)" />
```

Here `x` & `y` attributes are given but this not gives the image actual position. As much as i know in the

transform matrix `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` `e` & `f` gives the translated axis in the x and y respectively. But the

problem is that here both `( e & f )` are 0. Now i can i get the actual `x` any `y` for this image?

Comment: It's written all over. `x="335.27295"` `y="-421.28461"`

Comment: But this is not the actual x and y for the element

Comment: See [image element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElementXAttribute) from SVG documentation

Comment: oh are you looking for the x, y after applying the transformation matrix?

Comment: OK, I`ll calculate it for you and post an answer with an exaplaination, give me a few minutes..

Comment: See the question I posted above, let me know if you still need help

Comment: yes i need help because in my case e and f are 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming,

```
x="335.27295"
y="-421.28461"
```

Given the transformation matrix

```
a              b          e
c              d          f
0              0          1
```

Having the values

```
0.22297057     0.97482518 0
-0.97482518    0.22297057 0
0              0          1
```

Knowing

- a, d are responsible for scaling x, y respectivly
- e, f are responsible for transforming x, y respectivly

You`ll eventually get

```
newX = x * a + e
newY = y * d + f
```

Or,

```
newX = 335.27295 * 0.22297057 + 0 = 74.75
newY = -421.28461 * 0.22297057 + 0 = -93.93
```

Comment: Shouldn't the transformation matrix be `[[a c e][b d f][0 0 1]]` (i.e., b and c swaped compared to yours), as per http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined ?